# How to get the data of the clicked row in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a few table rows and in the last column of the respective rows there are two operations that can be performed.

```
        <div class="embedded-list-table-wrapper embedded-medium migration-status-list-container">
            <table class="list-table embedded-list-table no-truncate-td">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <a href="#list-table" class="table-sort table-sort-desc">
                                <span class="table-sort-text">Account Name</span>
                                <span class="table-sort-indicator"></span>
                            </a>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <a href="#list-table" class="table-sort table-sort-desc">
                                <span class="table-sort-text"># Batches Completed</span>
                            </a>
                        </th>

                        <th style="width:123px;">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items | limitTo : vm.pageSize : (vm.currentPage-1)*vm.pageSize">
                        <td class="table-link"><a  class="ng-binding" href="" target="_blank" ng-click="vm.setTenantId($event)">{{item.accountName}}</a></td>
                        <td class="table-text ng-binding">{{item.completedBatches}}</td>
                        <td class="table-input">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <div class="cog dropdown-toggle" ng-click="batch.showSettings = !batch.showSettings"></div>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu visible" ng-show="batch.showSettings">
                                        <li><span class="dropdown-category">Manage</span></li>
                                        <li class=""><a href="" ng-click="vm.removeAccount(item.accountName)">Remove from Panel</a></li>
                                        <li class=""><a href="#" ng-click="vm.setEncoreLink()">View</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Now this `<a>" in View` button will redirect me to a url that will look something like `https://encore.rackspace.com/accounts/<tenant-id>` . The `<tenant-id>` will come from first column `Account Name` value that we can split something like :

```
            vm.setEncoreLink = function($event){
                debugger;
                var tenant_id_text = $event.currentTarget.text;
                var tenant_id = tenant_id_text.substring(tenant_id_text.lastIndexOf("#")+1,tenant_id_text.lastIndexOf(")"));
                var encoreUrl = "https://encore.rackspace.com/accounts/"+tenant_id;
                $window.location.href=encoreUrl;
            }
```

**Provided the $event is passed from the first column value. 
How to access that and pass that so that tenant_id can be accessed ?
Or is there any other way out ?**

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Where in your scope has the tenant_id to start with? Is it in the item you're rendering?

Comment: @Paul there is no tenant id. We have to derive it from first column value. If we can get the first column value text an we can pass it to the function, we can split and get it accordingly there.

Comment: Why would you not just pass `item` to your `setEncoreLink` method so you can access its properties directly without having to try to do some crazy stuff with `$event`? BTW, you're not passing `$event` from your view so in the `setEncoreLink` method it will always be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it looks to me like the text you're trying to derive from is actually '{{item.accountName}}', correct? Also you weren't actually explicit, but from your sample code I'm assuming you're trying to do the `setEncoreLink` function.

So given that you can just do this:

`<li class=""><a href="#" ng-click="vm.setEncoreLink(item)">View</a></li>`

And then your function can be

```
vm.setEncoreLink = function(item){
                debugger;
                var tenant_id_text = item.accountName;
                var tenant_id = tenant_id_text.substring(tenant_id_text.lastIndexOf("#")+1,tenant_id_text.lastIndexOf(")"));
                var encoreUrl = "https://encore.rackspace.com/accounts/"+tenant_id;
                $window.location.href=encoreUrl;
            }
```